# Show predefined URL under WebGrid

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

When I pass some  **MODEL** to **VIEW** and this **MODEL** already has constructed **URL**.

How I can show it?

I tried `Html.ActionLink` but it always has host of the website. I don't need it.

Thank you!

```
  @grid.GetHtml(
                            tableStyle: "grid",
                            headerStyle: "head",
                            alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
                            rowStyle: "row",
                            selectedRowStyle: "selected-row",
                            columns: grid.Columns(
                                           grid.Column("Name", "Name", style: "column"),
                                      grid.Column("Price", "Price"),
                                           grid.Column(format: (item) => Html.ActionLink("ShopURL", "Buy", 
                                               new { @href = item.ShopURL}), style: "column-action")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are not actually setting the href of the link in your example.  The third parameter works out being your RouteValues, missing your @href setting.  The following should fix your problem:

```
@Html.ActionLink("LinkText", "SomeAction", "SomeController", null, new {@href = link})
```